# The declared package does not match the expected package for apache-commons

Tags: java, eclipse, external, libraries, apache-commons

I'm trying to add apache-commons to my fresh project but I got problems with packages after importing the source.

```
The declared package "org.apache.commons.math" does not match
the expected package "src.main.java.org.apache.commons.math"
```

What can I do?

Comment: Why do you "import the source" in the first place? Just download the jar file and put it in the build path. You shouldn't use the source files, and your own classes shouldn't be in the package org.apache.commons.math.

Comment: i added the jars firstly, but the code didn't compiled, my friend teacher told me that i need the source

Comment: @JBNizet  i have another source folder for my own classes

Comment: Your friend teacher was completely wrong. If you have a compilation error, then post your code, and post the exact and complete error message.

Comment: I do not have any code, i just want to add source to my project

Comment: You shouldn't. There is absolutely no reason to do that. Your project should contain your sources, not the sources of commons-math. commons-math is a library, and all you need to ue it is its jar file in your build path. You said "the code didn't compile": so, which code, then, if you say now that you have no code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Packages in Java translate into a folder hierarchy, both for the source files and the compiled class files. A **Source Folder** expected to contain the package `org.apache.commons.math` will contain files in a structure like `org/apache/commons/math/` where the **Source Folder** is the direct parent of `org`. Having an expected package of `src.main.java.org.apache.commons.math` means that `src/main/java` is *in* a **Source Folder** rather that being set *as* a **Source Folder**. Open your project's **Properties** dialog, go to the **Java Build Path** page, and correct the contents of the **Source** tab. If you're using Maven or another tool to compile your sources instead, fix that configuration directly.

Comment: Yeah, i just noticed that myself. Anyway, thanks for proper answer ! :)

Comment: Where you say "If you're using Maven or another tool to compile your sources instead, fix that configuration directly." What do you mean exactly?